# Ratio between two integrals

Tags: integration, limits

It should be easy to see that $\int_{0}^{\pi \over 2} \sin^2x dx = {\pi \over 4} $ and $\int_{0}^{\pi \over 2} 1 dx = {\pi \over 2}$. Let $a=\int_{\pi \over 2}^{k} \sin^2x dx$, and $b=\int_{\pi \over 2}^{k} 1 dx $. We have $\lim_{k \to \infty} {a\over b}={1\over 2}$. However, let $a'=\int_{\pi\over 2}^{k} {\sin^2x \over x^4} dx$ and $b'=\int_{\pi \over 2}^{k} {1\over x^4} dx $, then $\lim_{k \to \infty} {a'\over b'}\approx 0.711 \neq {1\over 2} $. I failed to understand why $\lim_{k \to \infty} {a'\over b'}$ is not $1\over 2$

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gmmvzwi2iv

Comment: It's not clear why, from your explanation, the limit should also be 1/2.

Comment: You're basically asking why $\sin^2X$ doesn't have the same mean on a distribution whose pdf is proportional to $x^{-4}$ on $[\pi/2,\,\infty)$ as it does for e.g. $X\sim U(0,\,\pi)$.

Comment: "Moby Dick" and "Much Ado About Nothing" are two very different books, even though they start with the same letter. How so? Well, just like that. Same thing with your integrals.